# Setting and reading CustData

Tags: docx4j

We currently have a need to embed data in a power point slide that will not be displayed. The power point API includes a Customer Data element for each slide which would fit out needs. 
The docx4j CommonSlideData class allows for the reading of this data but the CTCustomerData class that it returns only has an id.

What is the correct way to set are read the CustomerData?

Answer (score 0):

It's a relId to a CustomXML part:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.customerdata(v=office.14).aspx

See also https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/PowerPoint-2010-Use-Custom-794ffe88

For more on customxml parts, look at the docx part of docx4j, where they are used a lot.